# How to disable link_to_remote funcation after click made

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a link_to_remote method :

```
<%= link_to_remote "Country", :url =>{:controller =>'country',:action=>'get_country_info',:id=>@count_id.to_i},:update=>"Details6",:loading => "Element.show('loader');",:complete => "Element.hide('loader');"%>
```

i want to disable the link after user made click, I tried with `:before=>"this.style.display=none"` it removes the link ... i want to have disable nature. Can anyone help me out how can i implement this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a :disable\_with equivalent for link\_to\_remote?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358469/is-there-a-disable-with-equivalent-for-link-to-remote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related: [Is there a :disable_with equivalent for link_to_remote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358469/is-there-a-disable-with-equivalent-for-link-to-remote)

Answer (score 2):

I did the following thingy to fix it for link_to:

Add this somewhere in your helpers:

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module UrlHelper
      def link_to_with_disable(*args, &block)
        if block_given?
          link_to_without_disable(*args,&block)
        else
          html_options = args[2] || {}
          disable_with = html_options[:disable_with]
          if disable_with
            if html_options[:disable_with].kind_of? String
              html_options[:"data-onloadingtext"] = disable_with
             elsif html_options[:disable_with].kind_of? Array
              html_options[:"data-onloadingtext"] = disable_with[0] if disable_with[0]
              html_options[:"data-oncompletetext"] = disable_with[1] if disable_with[1]
            end
          end
          link_to_without_disable(*args)
        end
      end
      alias_method_chain :link_to, :disable unless method_defined?(:link_to_without_disable)
    end
  end
end
```

Then load a javascript file containing:

```
$("a[data-onloadingtext]").live("ajax:before", function(et, e){
  $(this).text($(this).attr('data-onloadingtext'))
         .attr('onclick','return false;')
         .addClass('disabled');
});
$("a[data-oncompletetext]").live("ajax:complete", function(et, e){
  $(this).text($(this).attr('data-oncompletetext'));
});
```

Now you can do stuff like:

```
<%= link_to 'foo', 'bar', :remote => true, :disable_with => 'foo_disabled' %>
```

and

```
<%= link_to 'foo', 'bar', :remote => true, :disable_with => ['foo_loading','foo_loaded'] %>
```

I'm very open to feedback ;) Still new to ruby, and trying to learn how to fix things neatly ;)

Comment: you should submit this to rails core

Answer (score 0):

it might be a bit messy but you can do an

```
<%= link_to_remote "Country", :url =>{:controller =>'country',:action=>'get_country_info',:id=>@count_id.to_i},:update => "Details6",:loading => "Element.show('loader');",:complete => "Element.hide('loader');", :href => "return false;" %>
```

return false in a link disables it(good for javascript functions so they won't continue to the link after doing something

Comment: Thanks for you response. but no luck, the link will be active after user clicks

Answer (score 0):

`link_to_remote item_masters_path, {},:onclick => "return false"`

```
=> "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"return false; new Ajax.Request('/item_masters/index', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:'authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('kzW0m2Vjg5I9IPeMs3hDMzQUFyyaBgVH35K0AEg77ls=')}); return false;\">/item_masters</a>"
```